# excel function searching multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet with a column (A) with dates. Some rows between dates are blank. I want to put a cell on another sheet that searches sheet1, column A for a particular date, and when that date is found, I want to get a value from another column, same row.

Example. I want to find date 7/1/12 in cells A2:A50 then show the result of column D, on that row, into another sheet. Can it be done?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: You need to be sure that only one particular date in mentioned; thus 7/1/12 exists only once! Is that the case?

Comment: there is only a single instance of each day of the month

Comment: That sounds logical.....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `VLOOKUP` function, with the following data sets:

*sheet1*: A2:D50; dates present in col. A, result in col. D

*sheet2*: A1="date to be found", B1="result"

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;sheet1!A:D;4;0)
```

Comment: I some locales, you must use comma (`,`) rather than semicolon (`;`) to separate arguments to Excel formula functions.

Comment: That's for sure a regional thing. I'm in CEST, and there semicolons are used!